# Collection View cell off center when swiping

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

When I swipe through my collectionView cells they are cut off the page for some reason even tho the first cell is fine. When I get the the last cell then swipe again it bounces and then the last cell displays correctly. [see video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15n2izpFtcX8j2m0S8Un6HJLW37_s2AdZ/view?usp=drivesdk)
In the video the blue is an imageView in the cell. Green, orange and purple are collectionView cells and white is the collectionView background.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any spaces between your cells. Please put some code where you are creating your cell and what's their width?

Comment: send your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first give the value of collection cell spacing `0`.
- add the code for collection-layout.

> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
>   collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath:
>   IndexPath) -> CGSize {
>       let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
>       let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
>       return CGSize(width: width, height: height) }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
>   collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt
>   Selection: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
>       return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
>   collectionViewLayout:
>   UICollectionViewLayout,minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt selection:
>   Int) -> CGFloat{
>       return 0 }
>
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
>   collectionViewLayout:
>   UICollectionViewLayout,minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt selection: Int)
>   -> CGFloat{
>       return 0 }

if still it doesn't work then send your code... :)

Comment: Setting the cell spacing as 0 fixed it. I can’t believe I didn’t check that.